# Generate a table in Latex with cells in different colours

Tags: latex

I am pursuing a PHD in Mathematics in Graph Theory. In my thesis I have to color a specific cell row (edge of a graph) of a table in Latex. Can this be done? I have only found a way that colors the entire row.

Comment: Hi! Please let us understand better if your point is to color the text in the cells or also the border of the cells (if they have one). Can you please post your own code, where you achieved coloring entire rows?

Answer (score 10):

You can color a specific cell using `\cellcolor` from the `xcolor` package:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r|c|l}
    A & B & C \\\hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
    x & y & \cellcolor{red!25}z
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, I didn't know this one! Also, one can combine: `\cellcolor{red!25}\color{blue}{z}`

Answer (score 1):

One first suggestion, to color the text in each of the cells manually (if your table is not too big):

```latex
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\definecolor{light-blue}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,1}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
\color{red}{Some text} & \color{light-blue}{and some other}\\
\color{cyan}{inside} & \color{green}{a table}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

produces the following table.

[image: screenshot of the output]

Default colors are `black`, `white`, `red`, `green`, `blue`, `cyan`, `magenta`, `yellow` and further details are included [here](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf).

Furthermore, to color the background of the cells, I advise the package called [`ytableau`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ytableau).